# How to Create a WordPress Plugin With Custom Post Type/Custom Field Features?

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, custom-field

One has one or more custom post types and custom fields - what would one need to add to make these into a functioning plugin?

e.g. code to initiate, activate, deactivate plugin; addition of CPT to admin menu.

If someone has time to write a full response, awesome, but I'd also be happy with being pointed to an article that covers this topic.

Comment: This is technically 2 questions, but keep in mind that a functioning plugin is a PHP file with a multi-line comment at the top with `Plugin Name: I'm a plugin` inside it, everything else is just code, there's nothing special other than putting it in the plugins folder and activating it

Comment: Could you elaborate a little? Are you looking for help starting out for the first time, or have you written WordPress plugins before, just never with custom post types?